# $f(x,y)$ satisfying sufficient condition for quasi-concavity for adjacent regions, but not the union of the regions?

Tags: functions, derivatives, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Is it possible?

> For example, is it possible for a function $f(x,y)$
>
> - to satisfy the sufficient condition for quasi concavity -- (the sufficient condition on the determinants of the leading principle
>     minors of the bordered hessian) -- for $(x,y)\in (4,5)\times (2,3)$,
> - and to also satisfy them for $(x,y) \in (4,5)\times (0,2)$,
> - but the function to not be quasi concave over $(4,5)\times (0,3)$?

---

Some comments:

- The intervals I used in my example don't matter, I just used any numbers in $(0,\infty)$
- Graphically, I think I can imagine such a function. For example, suppose the function is increasing in $y$ for $y\in (2,3)$ but decreasing in $y$ for $y\in (0,2)$.

  - In such a case I think the "upper contour sets" will be in different directions in the two regions (by different directions I mean in one region higher values of $y$ are better and in the other lower values of $y$ are better)

> If the function's bordered hessian satisfies the sufficient condition for quasi-concavity over two adjacent regions, but the function is not quasi-concave over the union of the regions, what does this mean for the derivative of the function?
>
> - To elaborate, we can write the sufficient conditions for quasi-concavity in terms of derivatives. In the situation I have described I think the condition must be violated at the border between the two regions. **Doesn't this mean that the first or second derivatives must have some sort of discontinuity at the border of the two regions?**

lastly, **if one of the regions was a closed interval** -- i.e. $[0,2]$, then would satisfying the sufficient condition for quasi-concavity over the two adjacent regions imply quasi-concavity over the union of the regions?